# Unable to join worker nodes onto k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I'm setting up k8s cluster on bare metal using the following [documentation](https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/kubernetes/beginners/install/ubuntu/18.04/install-k8s.html).

I've reached this step and I'm running this only on the master node.

[image]

Next step is to join worker nodes. But when I try I get the following error.

```
root@k8sworker02:~# kubeadm join 192.168.10.10:6443 --token arsj3t.i1qftwqhu7mwacr6         --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:cccf7182d907eb154a0669120976b324d562719bc662f0a6b24d57a2a7e85889
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: E0810 15:06:49.849438    4541 remote_runtime.go:925] "Status from runtime service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService"
time="2022-08-10T15:06:49Z" level=fatal msg="getting status of runtime: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1alpha2.RuntimeService"
, error: exit status 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

I've started containerd using `systemctl status containerd`. Yet I still get the above error on all worker nodes.

```
root@k8sworker01:~# systemctl status containerd
● containerd.service - containerd container runtime
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/containerd.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-08-10 14:43:28 UTC; 59min ago
       Docs: https://containerd.io
    Process: 689 ExecStartPre=/sbin/modprobe overlay (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
   Main PID: 717 (containerd)
      Tasks: 9
     Memory: 68.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/containerd.service
             └─717 /usr/bin/containerd
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: From the error error shared  it states that contained is not running.  To start contqinerd it should be systemctl start containerd. I think it might be a typo for the command you had shared Please share the containerd status.

Comment: @NatarajMedayhalI I've added the status output. Maybe I wonder if should copy the kubelet.conf from master to worker? Or we only run the join command and do nothing else? I'm not sure why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to remove the follwing file and restart containerd.

```
rm -f /etc/containerd/config.toml

systemctl restart containerd

kubeadm join 192.168.10.10:6443  .....
```

Run the following commands to export `kubeclt configs`

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
touch $HOME/.kube/config
chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
sudo cp -i  /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf $HOME/.kube/config
```

Check the nodes

```
kubectl get nodes
```